# How to see bitcoin in my wallet

Tags: wallet, money-transfer

I bought bitcoin from coinmama and sent it to my bitcoin core wallet, but after the syncing was done I don't see that my wallet has been credited. Has anyone else experienced this issue??

Thanks!

Comment: have you got the address public key you sent the btc to? check the address on a blockexplorer to see if the funds are there

Answer (score 1):

A few questions to ask:

1. Did you send it to the right address?
2. Is the address's private key controlled by/imported into the bitcoin core wallet? E.g. `$ bitcoin-cli importprivkey <WIF>`
3. Make sure the transaction has been confirmed on the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

You should look up your address on a block explorer (*e.g.* [blocktrail](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC) or [blockchain.info](https://www.blockchain.com/en/explorer)). Bitcoin transactions are public, so if yours was successful, you will see it in a block explorer.

If your transaction is visible at your address in a block explorer and *not* visible through your wallet, it means that your wallet is incompletely synchronized. If your transaction is not visible in a block explorer, it could mean coinmama didn't send it (or sent it to the wrong address). They should have given you a *transaction ID*, which you can also look up in a block explorer.